# What happens behind the scenes when `-e` env vars are passed into a docker container?

Tags: docker, containerd

As an experiment, I'm setting environment variables in my Docker container in two ways: using the `-e` option, and using an `environment` file mounted to `/etc/environment` inside the container. The file has one line:

```
FROM_ENV_FILE=true
```

My `docker run` command:

```
docker run -de FROM_CMD_LINE=true -v $(pwd)/environment:/etc/environment ubuntu:14.04 sleep infinity
```

When I run `docker exec b20543b507e3 cat /etc/environment` I do see that this file is mounted properly and contains my value, however I'm only seeing `FROM_CMD_LINE` set when I run `printenv`, so it appears that my /etc/environment file is getting ignored.

My question is more than just *why doesn't /etc/environment work in my ubuntu:14.04 docker image?*. I'm looking for an answer that explains what  Docker does to set up a process's environment to make available the custom environment variables passed in via `-e` to all running processes in the container, so then I'll hopefully understand why `/etc/environment` is getting ignored in the container.

The relevant runtime details that I'm working with are pasted below.

```
docker version

Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:13:02 2018
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:22:38 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

Looking at the [release notes](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-ce/#stable-releases) for 18.03.1-ce:

> Containerd: update to 1.0.3 release [moby/moby#36749](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36749)

I'm at the point where I'm digging through the `containerd` source code, but I was hoping someone already familiar with the container runtime could help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When any process is spawned in Linux (using the `fork`/`execve` system calls), its environment is explicitly specified by passing an array with variables to the `execve`. When Docker starts the container (i.e. it spawns the root process of the container), it aggregates all the variables passed using the `-e` argument and adds them to the list of the environment variables which must be set to the container's main process.

However, Docker does not know anything about `/etc/environment`, which belongs to the container and is internal to its filesystem, be it mounted from outside or not. This file is owned by the Linux PAM system (which is responsible for authentication) and is used when someone logs in to set the common environment variables for the authentication session. You may check it by running `su` inside your container:

```
$ docker run -v $PWD/environment:/etc/environment -it ubuntu:14.04 bash
root@4902dd72b49b:/# env | grep ENV
root@4902dd72b49b:/# su -
root@4902dd72b49b:/# env | grep ENV
FROM_ENV_FILE=true
```

When you run `su`, an authentication session starts, thus, `/etc/environment` file is used.

So, you should not try using this file to set the variables for the container's main process. This file has different purpose and Docker does not know about it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I think I understand, just bear with me for a quick follow-up so I fully understand: basically the Docker process - in the host OS - spawns the container's main process, setting the environment variables passed in from `-e`, but since it's outside of the container, it knows nothing about the contents of /etc/environment (or any environment-setting files from within the container's filesystem for that matter) and so anything inside of the container's file system is inapplicable to the environment of the container's main process. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Note, that, formally speaking, Docker is able to inspect container's filesystem, but `/etc/environment` is just a configuration file of a particular library (`libpam`), so, for Docker this is just a plaintext file without any special meaning.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for taking the time to explain this.